# R conditional loop, multiple lists

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, logic, control-flow

I need help stepping through a second loop in R when a test fails in my first loop. Here's the logic:

1. to start use config_list[1] from list
2. then download file path_list[1] from list
3. check if file passes test,
4. if so, download path_list[1 + 1] file from list and go back to step 3
5. if not, change config to next in list and go back to step 2 for failed file

Here's how far I've gotten:

```
path_list <- list("path1", "path2", "path3")
config_list <- list("a", "b", "c")


for (con in config_list) {
  con[1] # set initial config
  for (val in path_list) {
    print(paste(val, "downloaded")) # download file
    if (val == "path2"){ # check if file passes some test
      con[1 + 1] # if above test fails change to con[1 + 1]
      print(paste(val, "downloaded")) # download file again with new config ???
    }
    print(val)
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you modify the example to include how you would like to use `config_list`? At the moment, it is not included at all so folks trying to help are likely a bit confused about how to integrate it. Also, nothing here is an actual list, which is a specific data structure in R: `path_list` and `config_list` are both vectors. In your data, are they in vector or list format? This would have implications on how to approach this issue. Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith thanks for the feedback, hopefully its more clear now. I can covert the lists to vectors if it makes for a cleaner solution. I want the loop to move to the new config[1+1] until there's another failed test and then move forward 1 on the list again.